# Possible to set BroadcastReceiver priority programmatically?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

Is it possible to set the priority attribute of a BroadcastReceiver programmatically or can it only be done in XML?
Relevant documents include:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html

It doesn't seem so, but I don't fully understand the relationship of android.R.styleable to a given application and its activities...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't set priority on `BroadcastReceiver` (or `Activity`) objects, but instead on the `IntentFilter` object(s) that cause these items to be started.

With that in mind, [`IntentFilter.setPriority()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority(int)) is what you want to use.